# java tray how to implements mouse hover and leave event?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, trayicon

I'm trying to achieving an effect ,it's  when your mouse is hover the tray,the tray will pop a window and when your mouse leave the tray,the pop window will disappear;
The method is dose not work,like this:

```
trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouse exited!");
        }   
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouse entered!");
        }
    });
```

The next method can only listen to mouse move event:

```
trayIcon.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouse moved!");
        }
    });
```

It's work,but the pop window dose not disappear when mouse leave the tray.
It's not my expected;
How can I do,maybe you can give me some advice! Thank you!

Comment: What tray and what window? Maybe post pictures demonstrating what you want.